# Utility type to convert an abstract class to a non-abstract subclass?

Tags: abstract, typescript-utility

I have an abstract class, and I would like to generate a type that matches any non-abstract subclass of that type, not its instance. Is this possible?

```js
abstract class A {
}
function b(type: NonAbstractDescendant<typeof A>) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the function (`b`) needs `type` to create instances. This suggests a type like `{ new() : A }` (with the appropriate parameter types), or if static properties and/or methods are required `{ new(): A } & typeof A`. In either case, this only matches subclasses of which the constructors take compatible parameters.

It is possible to avoid repeating the constructor parameters like `{ new(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof B>): B } & typeof B` but it is well possible that this is longer than simply repeating them.

An example:

```js
abstract class A {}
class D extends A {}
function f(cons: { new() : A } & typeof A): A {
    return new cons();
}
f(D);
```